# How to set values of a Spinner object with an Array List of String elements?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, spinner

I am trying to set the values of an Spinner with an Array List but it only works with the function "arrayOf()".

I tried converting the List to Typed Array bit it didn´t work.

It seems that the Array List adds all the names of the cites and when I run the app the spinner shows them all but it always return a null value.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val listaciudades = ArrayList<String>()

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("Localidad").get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                var nombre = document.data["nombre"] as String
                listaciudades.add(nombre)
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fallo al guardar datos en Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), listaciudades.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val spinnerInicio = requireView().findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerInicio)
        val spinnerDestino = requireView().findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerDestino)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaciudades)
        spinnerInicio.adapter = arrayAdapter
        spinnerDestino.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

[Running app, spinners do not show first value of Array List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrSav.jpg)

[Spinners contains the values of Array List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmntT.jpg)

[Options selected on both spinners but return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmBe6.jpg)

Comment: can you please elaborate and also can you please tell your use case??

Comment: An Enum is a good choice for static information.
You can also make an xml in your resource folder (where your strings.xml is) and create a string-array within that.

Comment: how are you initializing list?

Comment: List gets data from Firebase Firestore.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the List you have into a typed array using `toTypedArray()`; here is the full code :

```kotlin
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list.toTypedArray())
```